# Literal Find and replace exact match. Ignore regex

Tags: powershell

I have a list of strings (paths) and I want to allow a user to do a find/replace on them.

Seems simple, but the problem is the paths and replacements often contain characters that are interpreted as regex.

I want to do a very simple find / replace of exactly what the user types without making them enter regex matches or escape replacement text.

I have no control over the original data or the input replacement. I thought there would be some cmdlet that would allow string escaping or a literal match. I'm coming up blank here.

I'm sure there's an easy way to literally find/replace without regex getting involved.

```
# Example only all data will be entered by users.

$string = "\\server24.domain.com\business\staff\local_staff_25\FAYearEnd"
$find = "\business\staff\local_staff_25\"
$replace = "\local_staff_25$\"

$string -replace $find,$replace
The regular expression pattern \business\staff\local_staff_25\ is not valid.
At line:6 char:1
+ $string -replace $find,$replace
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (\business\staff\local_staff_25\:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
```

Comment: More info in the linked answer, but you're looking for the `[RegEx]::Escape()` method.

Comment: @briantist Thanks for finding that. [RegEx]::Escape() certainly is one way. The simplest way I found was using $string.replace() rather than -replace.  I didn't realize they were different.